# Minecraft Single Player commands not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

So I'm on Mac OS X Lion and I tried to install single player commands. I have minecraft 1.2.5. I did the automatic install, it worked fine and now when I open minecraft a little thing come up at the bottom that says `single player commands` and some other stuff. However when I try to type / and a command, this does not work. It just does nothing (or does the minecraft command for the given key I pressed). Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried opening the chat box normally, then just typing a `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use SPC you must open the chat window, then type in a command. To open the chat window, type <kbd>T</kbd>, then your command.